# Expanding upon sequences in dataframe and stacking the results into one column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, expand, street-address

I have a series of 170,000 addresses that I'm in the process of geocoding. I need to expand  the range of addresses provided in the dataset, so I can geocode all possibilities. For example, if you look at row 1 in the first data frame, I'm trying to have "1-5 Fake St" be expanded into new rows that read 1 Fake St, 3 Fake St, and 5 Fake St (NOTE: 2 Fake St and 4 Fake St are absent because they would be on the other side of the street).

Here's an example of the data:

```
df <- data.frame("ID"=c(1:5),
             "Address_From"=c(1,3,2,5,1),
             "Address_To"=c(5,5,8,5,NA),
             "St_name"= c("Fake","Unreal","Nope","Road","No"),
             "suffix"=c("St","Ave","Ave","Rd","Way"),
             "parcel"=c(2:6), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Current data frame:

[image: Current Data Frame 1]

I'm trying to expand the data to each potential address in each "Address_From - Address_To" sequence so that I end up with an individual address in each row. Here's what I'm hoping to get to:

Ideal data frame:

[image: Ideal Data Frame]

I've tried using some ifelse statements:

```
df$sequence <- NA
df$sequence <- ifelse((!is.na(df$Address_From) <= !is.na(df$Address_To)), 0,
                    (ifelse((!is.na(df$Address_From) == (!is.na(df$Address_To)+1)),1,
                            ifelse((!is.na(df$Address_From) > !is.na(df$Address_To) & !is.na(df$Address_From) == !is.na(df$Address_To)+1),
                                   (seq(!is.na(df$Address_To), !is.na(df$Address_From), by=2)),NA))))
```

But I keep getting the same error:

```
Error in seq.default(!is.na(df$Address_From), !is.na(df$Address_To),  :
'from' must be of length 1
```

I also not sure how to convert the desired sequences (e.g. 1,3,5) into individual rows (e.g. 1 Fake St, 3 Fake St, 5 Fake St).

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't understand the part about even and odd--what do those change exactly, and how?

Comment: Sorry, after rereading this, I realize I need more explanation. If you look at row 1 in the first data frame, I'm trying to have "1-5 Fake St" be expanded into new rows that read 1 Fake St, 3 Fake St, and 5 Fake St (NOTE: 2 Fake St and 4 Fake St are absent because they would be on the other side of the street).

Comment: I first tried a series of "ifelse" statements that built out a new column that listed the sequences (e.g. 1-5 became 1,3,5) but I wasn't sure how to convert them to new rows.

Comment: Okay, any code you've written, even if it doesn't work, and this explanation should get edited into the question

Answer (score 0):

I use `mapply` to add a list column with vectors to the original data, and then `tidyr::unnest` to expand this into multiple rows. The missing values make this noticeably harder, I handle them as special cases.

```
missing_pieces = is.na(df$Address_From) | is.na(df$Address_To)
df$Address_num[!missing_pieces] = with(df[!missing_pieces, ], mapply(FUN = seq, from = Address_From, to = Address_To, by = 2))
df$Address_num[missing_pieces] = list(NA)
result = tidyr::unnest(data = df, Address_num)
result$Address_num = dplyr::coalesce(result$Address_num, result$Address_From, result$Address_To)
result
#    ID Address_From Address_To St_name suffix parcel Address_num
# 1   1            1          5    Fake     St      2           1
# 2   1            1          5    Fake     St      2           3
# 3   1            1          5    Fake     St      2           5
# 4   2            3          5  Unreal    Ave      3           3
# 5   2            3          5  Unreal    Ave      3           5
# 6   3            2          8    Nope    Ave      4           2
# 7   3            2          8    Nope    Ave      4           4
# 8   3            2          8    Nope    Ave      4           6
# 9   3            2          8    Nope    Ave      4           8
# 10  4            5          5    Road     Rd      5           5
# 11  5            1         NA      No    Way      6           1
```

I left the original IDs, if you want to overwrite them with `result$ID = 1:nrow(result)`, I'll leave that to you.